# Git vs SVN - Network Performance (for backup)

Tags: svn, git

Which is better suited for transferring large files with frequent updates over limited bandwidth?  I Haven't been able to find any comparisons out there.

**UPDATE**

To not preclude other solutions, is something better suited to sending deltas to large files?  (Have tried Unison)

Comment: Why not use *rsync* (that is what Unison uses), or true backup tool, like e.g. *bup* (which uses Git as backend)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With large and oft-changed binary files, both git and svn should be basically the same for push/commit and pull/update operations. With large files, you're limited by the size of the diff you're sending. Both git and svn will do compression, so nobody obviously wins here unless one of them works better with your file type.

However, there is one critical point: *Cloning* a git repository of this sort will be slow. This is because clone will have to pull down all of those diffs, instead of only the latest snapshot.

So if you can avoid the `clone` command, specifically, you're free to go with whatever tool has the best support for you.

(I will also suggest Dropbox as a good candidate for this task.)

Comment: A bit more context.  The files are DB Backups; my understanding is that new content is appended.  To that end, a clone should be about the same size as the file?  I love dropbox, but its not quite right for this.

Comment: More on dropbox, though, it works great on 1GB TrueCrypt virtual drives.  They update very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Unison or rsync are probably your best bet. Storing lots of large binary files in a source code control system can cause headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Can't give you concrete numbers right now, but I use SVN and git and the last one is *way* faster.

More propaganda: http://whygitisbetterthanx.com/#git-is-fast

> Git can use four major network protocols to transfer data: Local, Secure Shell (SSH), Git, and HTTP.
>
> ...
>
> The Git protocol is the fastest transfer protocol available. If you’re serving a lot of traffic for a public project or serving a very large project that doesn’t require user authentication for read access, it’s likely that you’ll want to set up a Git daemon to serve your project.

From http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html

And an informal memo describing the protocol: http://git-scm.com/gitserver.txt

Comment: and SVN can use http or svn protocol. SSH is likely to be very slow due to the encryption of all files, and local is almost never going to be the one you want, in a network environment :)